# Creating Table Relationships

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am working on a VB.net (VS-2010, Win XP Pro 2 SP3), Employee Management Project. I need to keep track of Employee Leave Attendance and also each Equipment assigned to an Employee. How can I achieve this using SQLlite.

It will be very useful if you could provide me with examples as I am completely new to the field of SQL and VB.net

I think this can be done with two tables where one has the primary key while the other has a foreign key, but I am not sure. Also how many tables will I need for storing data in  Leave and Equipment Form.

I went through other questions but I was unable to figure out a solution for my problem.
(Sorry, I cannot provide with images as this site prevents me from posting images without 10 reps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most problems are only as complex, and as simple as you make them. Out of habbit, nearly all tables end up with a unique ID field. There are exceptions, which I will call "link" tables, eg, ones that provide connection details between two data tables.

Now, in your senario

You would need a "holiday" table, where each row will contain the employee unique ID and either  a start/finish date, eg, if they take half a day, it needs to be visible, or, just a year and value, eg in 2011, I booked, 2 lots of 35 hours, and 1 lot of 4 hours eg, Ive taken 2 weeks and half a day.

For the equipment, you would need a data table, since an item can only got to 1 employee, it depends if you're going to use this for booking or not, but if its just like a library, eg I currently have a loaner laptop, then you can just have an employee field in the equipment table.  If you need a booking system, then you would require link tables and more complex.

Best way to work out your tables is to try and group your data, and then write the items on peices of paper and see how you as a human do it. After a while you end up able to do so in your head.